# Is it possible to merge two geoserver layers into one (merging) and export as KML?

Tags: geoserver, kml

I have used the KML reflector in order to get a geoserver layer into KML.
Now what I want to do is to merge two layers (which might have different geometries) and export them into a KML file.
Is something like this possible with openlayers or geoserver api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a request with `layers=layer1,layer2` and you should find both of them in the generated KML